# How can I draw only the silhouette of an SVG icon in Qt5 in a color of my choosing?

Tags: svg, colors, icons, qt5, paint

In Qt5 (I am using 5.8 on Ubuntu 16.04 amd64), drawing **SVG** is easy. However I want to use SVG to represent *icons*, and in that context it would be really useful if I could draw them in a *single color* as *silhouettes* (kind of like a font icon such as font awesome).

Is this possible to do without writing too much custom code? Can it be done easily using QtCreator UI designer for example?

Comment: Depending on the precise nature of the SVG you may be able to use one of [`QImage::createAlphaMask`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#createAlphaMask), [`QImage::createHeuristicMask`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#createHeuristicMask) or [`QImage::createMaskFromColor`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#createMaskFromColor) to generate a bitmap that you can then render in the desired colour to use in a `QIcon`.

Comment: @G.M. Thanks! But I will need a full alpha channel, not just a single-bit mask. I think I managed to pull it off using compositing, see my answer below. However I was hoping for a little less code. Doing this this way I will have to re-implement all widgets that will use the SVG icons :(

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve this. It is probably not the best (which is why I asked the question in the first place), but until something better shows up I will use this. Here is what my result looks like:

[image]

Notice that the gray area is the window, and not touched at all.

First of all, you will need an *off-screen* `QPixmap` to render to. In my implementation I already had one for doing double-buffering. Since re-rendering a complex SVG at every redraw is not recommended you should have one too.

In the "the size of the double-buffer changed and we need to re-render it" part of my code, I simply clear the double buffer to transparent with:

```
mDoubleBuffer.fill(QColor("#00000000"));
```

Then I render the svg as normal with:

```
QPainter painter(mDoubleBuffer);
mSVG->render(&painter);
```

And finally, in the end, I put the following:

```
if(mSilhouetteEnabled) {
    painter.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_SourceIn);
    painter.fillRect(QRect(0,0,w,h), mSilhouetteForeground);
}
```

By switching composition mode of painter to `QPainter::CompositionMode_SourceIn` and drawing a solid color rectangle covering the entire area of the double buffer, it will in effect replace only the color, leaving the alpha channel alone.

When we then draw this carefully prepared double-buffer onto the screen it will be a solid color silhouette of the SVG with full alpha channel.